# How to invoke method with array parameter

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, multidimensional-array, methods

I'm trying to print a 2d grid with random numbers and another equally sized grid with -1s in place of the numbers that are evenly divisible by 3. I finished pretty much everything, but I cant figure out how to make the following line work: **Arraycopy = c.createCoords({10,10});**

I'm know I'm supposed to call the method with an int[][], I just cant remember how.

Here's all of the code just in-case:

```
public class practice
{

   public int [][] createArray(int rSize, int cSize)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[][] array = new int [rSize] [cSize];
         for (int row = 0; row <array.length; row++)  
       {
           for(int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++)
           {
             array[row][col] = r.nextInt(25);

           }

       }
         return array;
    }


    public void print2DArray(int[][] Array)
    {
       for (int row = 0; row <Array.length; row++)  
       {
           for(int col = 0; col < Array[0].length; col++)
           {
               System.out.print(Array[row][col] + "\t");
           }
            System.out.println("\n");
       } 
    }
public int[][] createCoords(int[][] Array)
{
    int [] [] coord = {
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    {-1,-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}

};
    for (int row = 0; row <coord.length; row++)  
       {
           for(int col = 0; col < coord[0].length; col++)
           {
               System.out.print(coord[row][col] + "\t");
           }
            System.out.println("\n");
}

    for (int row = 0; row <coord.length; row++)  
       {
           for(int col = 0; col < Array[row].length; col++)
           {
               if(Array[row][col] %3 == 0)
               coord[row][col] = -1;  

       }

       }
    return coord;

}

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        practice c = new practice();

      int [][] myArray; 
      int [][] Arraycopy;
      myArray = c.createArray(10, 10); 
     Arraycopy = c.createCoords({10,10});
     c.print2DArray(Arraycopy);
      c.print2DArray(myArray);




    }


}
```

Comment: `print2DArray(new int[][]{{1,2,2},{3,3,4}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method takes an `int[][]` as parameter, `{{10,10}}` could work because it is an `int[1][2]` but it is apparently not your goal.

I'd suggest to use `myArray` directly here.

---

### Solution

Replace

```
c.createCoords({10, 10});
```

with

```
c.createCoords(myArray);
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. All of the numbers in the second grid are -1s though. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it so the -1s only appear when the number is evenly divisible by 3?

Comment: I think you can but am not sure. But I do know that asking a new question on an existing one is not a good idea at all. You'll narrow the scope of the question and change the context of the original one.